# C# : inserting data from one database to another

Tags: c#, sql

How can I add dynamic data from one database to another one?

I am using the following code, it works fine for inserting static data but how can I make it add data dynamically into my database?

I already connected to the source database and I can see all the tables

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var container = GetProphetApiContainerForRequest();

        var newContact = new Contact()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),             // ID is necessary for creation.
                FirstName = "Doe ",               // For Example:FirstName = tableName.FirstName
                LastName = "Joe",                //For Example:LastName= tableName.LastName
                CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Email = "xx@yyyy.com",          // For Example:Email = tableName.Email
                BusinessPhone = "916 XXX XXXX",//For Example:BusinessPhone= tableName.PhoneNumber
            };

        // create
        container.AddToContacts(newContact);
        container.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to copy certain items from one table to another? Just get a List<Contact> and then you can foreach(var contact in someList) container.Add(contact);

Comment: get the data to insert from the args[] variable. When executing your app would be like: "D:\\yourapp.exe doe john 2015/8/13 email@email.com 915-000-0000"

Comment: @Broken_Window how can i connect with using `ODBC data connection` to pervasive database and use `args[]`?

Comment: @Knife that's a different approach, I was wrong, I though the app received the data to insert. Look here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/pervasive/ then you must extract the desired data from the source DB with a Select clause, store the data into variables, and using an Insert clause, store them into your desire table in your database. More info: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp . You may need a Datatable http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/UseDataTabletoupdatetableinDatabase.htm